# PHP Warning: Missing argument 1

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm pretty new to web designing and very eager to learn! I am currently working on a wordpress theme I've purchased and found the error log in the FTP server and was wondering if this is something I should be worried about or not?

It says

> "[09-Sep-2014 01:58:36] PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for
>   kage_get_list_services(), called in
>   /home2/neteffec/public_html/temp/wp-content/themes/kage-pro/template-homepage.php
>   on line 21 and defined in
>   /home2/neteffec/public_html/temp/wp-content/themes/kage-pro/functions.php
>   on line 428"

Please let me know if you need more information! Thanks!

-Jason

Comment: Most of the time, warnings are no big deal but I try my best to fix them. It mean in your function there's probably more than 1 argument and 1 is missing. Can you please post the codes related to line 21 in `template-homepage.php` and line 428 of `functions.php`?

Comment: This is the home page php: 

> $services_testimonials = kage_get_list_services();

and this is the functions.php:


        

> if ( ! function_exists( 'kage_get_list_services' ) ) : function
> kage_get_list_services($n) {
>     global $wp_query;
>     $args = array(
>         'post_type' => 'service',
>         'orderby' => 'menu_order',   'order' => 'ASC',   'posts_per_page' => $n
>     );  $wp_query->query( $args );
>     return new WP_Query( $args ); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message means that you did not pass in the required argument `$n` to the function `kage_get_list_services`. That's because your code is:

```
$services_testimonials = kage_get_list_services();
```

It should be:

```
//Pass whatever $n is supposed to be
$services_testimonials = kage_get_list_services( 13 );
```

The difference between required and non required arguments is if they have a default value. For example, you could change the function to be:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'kage_get_list_services' ) )
{

    function kage_get_list_services($n = 10)
    { 
        global $wp_query;
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'service', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => $n ); 
        $wp_query->query( $args ); 
        return new WP_Query( $args );
    }
}
```

In the above example, if you pass nothing, $n would be 10.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Don, I am a bit confused in why the code has 13 inside the brackets? could you please explain? Thank you!

Comment: @JasonHan 13 is just an example. As you can see from the code, `$n` is the number of posts returned from the query to show per page. So you could choose, 5, 8, 21, or whatever you want.